# MapController calls do not work inside of event handler?

Tags: android, google-maps, scroll, android-mapview

I'm trying to move the map with a 3-finger gesture, rather than one.
If I do a scrollBy() or setMapCenter() in my main activity, things seem to work as expected.
Howevver, if I make these calls inside of my ACTION_MOVE, for example, they seem to have no effect.
Posting doesn't really work well either.

There's another issue - the event.getX/Y() are floats, and the mapController.scrollBy() takes ints - as real-time dragging at normal speeds seems to require the sub-int resolution, making real-time updading hard to do.

And it seems really odd which methods are on the mapView and which on the mapController.

**UPDATE** : scrollBy() when executed in the event handler will move any overlays, but not the underlying map

So basicially what I want to be able "return true" form ACTION_MOVE and so have my code rather than the base code handle map tracking via user gesture

Comment: If you add a feature request to AML i'll look at adding it. - https://github.com/chrisjenx/AndroidMapLibrary/issues

Answer (score 0):

You may have to post a slight delay,

Something like:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

// Method Block
{
  handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() 
  { 
    // Code etc
  }, 500);
}
// End code block
```

When ever I play with map stuff, allot of the controller actions have to have be fired after the map has stopped being touched.. (I know that sounds like a pain).

I have written quite a bit of map library stuff (Android Map Library) and know what you mean where nothing seems to happen. Or the map just seems to ignore inputs, the only way I have managed it was with delayed controller commands.

Let me know your thoughts and I might be able to help a bit more.

Cheers,
Chris